# Python Pandas pivot with values equal to simple function of specific column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

```
import pandas as pd
olympics = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv')

    Edition  NOC   Medal
0      1896  AUT  Silver
1      1896  FRA    Gold
2      1896  GER    Gold
3      1900  HUN  Bronze
4      1900  GBR    Gold
5      1900  DEN  Bronze
6      1900  USA    Gold
7      1900  FRA  Bronze
8      1900  FRA  Silver
9      1900  USA    Gold
10     1900  FRA  Silver
11     1900  GBR    Gold
12     1900  SUI  Silver
13     1900  ZZX    Gold
14     1904  HUN    Gold
15     1904  USA  Bronze
16     1904  USA    Gold
17     1904  USA  Silver
18     1904  CAN    Gold
19     1904  USA  Silver
```

I can pivot the data frame to have some aggregate value

```
pivot = olympics.pivot_table(index='Edition', columns='NOC', values='Medal', aggfunc='count')

NOC      AUT  CAN  DEN  FRA  GBR  GER  HUN  SUI  USA  ZZX
Edition                                                  
1896     1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1900     NaN  NaN  1.0  3.0  2.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
1904     NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  4.0  NaN
```

Rather than having the total number of medals in *values=* , I am interested to have a tuple (a triple) with (#Gold, #Silver, #Bronze), (0,0,0) for NaN

How do I do that succinctly and elegantly?

No need to use pivot_table, as pivot is perfectly fine with tuple for a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `value_counts` to count all medals
- create multi-index for all combinations of countries, dates, medals
- `reindex` with `fill_values=0`

---

```
counts = df.groupby(['Edition', 'NOC']).Medal.value_counts()

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [c.values for c in counts.index.levels], names=counts.index.names)
counts = counts.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).unstack('Medal')
counts = counts[['Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold']]

pd.Series([tuple(l) for l in counts.values.tolist()], counts.index).unstack()
```

[image]